# Wrong value with TextBox.Text after DatePicker

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, datepicker

I'm using asp.net webforms in order to make reportings with the use of ReportViewer.

In one report, I want to allow the user to select date.

For that, I search for first day and last day of last month and set them from the Page_Load :

```
this.TextBox1.Text = FirstDayOfMonthDateTime.ToString(dd/MM/yyyy);
this.TextBox2.Text = LastDayOfPreviousMonthDateTime.ToString(dd/MM/yyyy);
```

At this point, all is ok, and datepicker run on the UI :

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="datePicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" class="datePicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
... 
// put all datepickers
        $(".datePicker").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
```

When I change the value of this label by using datepicker, it's ok from the UI, but when user clicks on button, code behind didn't give me good date:

```
protected void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = this.TextBox1.Text;
        }
```

It gives me the date that i've set in the Page_Load and not the text i've set with datepicker!

How and Why? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem of postback. you have to write the postBock condition in your Page_Load method

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
   this.TextBox1.Text = FirstDayOfMonthDateTime.ToString(dd/MM/yyyy);
   this.TextBox2.Text = LastDayOfPreviousMonthDateTime.ToString(dd/MM/yyyy);
}
```

This is a link about the postback property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx